# Categorization of Data using Python

Tags: python, excel, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I have a set of keywords to look for in a column and based on those I want to categorise the fields. Say if a cell has value "Accountant", "auditor", "bank", "cashier" etc, I want to add a new column Categories and reflect those fields as "Finance Jobs". [image]

I know how to do this in excel, but the file is about 80mbs and its way too slow. I was thinking of using Python but have very minimal experience in that.

[image: Sample Data]

I was thinking of using dictionaries, but don't know what and how to look for, achieving the same result.

Can anyone help me regarding this?

**EDIT: I have 150+ keywords and around 30 categories.**

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df['new_column'] = np.where(df['keywords'].isin(["Accountant", "auditor", "bank", "cashier"], "Finance Jobs", 'Other Jobs')
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention earlier. But I have 150+ keywords and around 30 categories, wouldn't it be untidy if I kept writing it like this?

Comment: @GIRIXH please edit your question and explain clearly about the data and what you want

Comment: Yes, it would be untidy - but you _need_ to define your 150 keywords : 30 categories mapping _somehow_

Comment: @GIRIXH you can prepare a dictionary of 30 categories and 150 keywords and then using the above code loop over the whole dictionary